# Why, rails server not running in zsh terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

After installing zsh i'm unable to start rails server i'm getting the following error:

In bash it is working properly

**Error:**

```
╭─love@Love ~/rails/nbt1 ‹system› ‹master*› 
╰─➤  rs
Could not find rake-10.1.0 in any of the sources
╭─love@Love ~/rails/nbt1 ‹system› ‹master*› 
╰─➤  bundle                                                                                                                                7 ↵
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:243:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /var/lib/gems  (Errno::EACCES)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:243:in `fu_mkdir'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:217:in `mkpath'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:215:in `reverse_each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:215:in `mkpath'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:201:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:201:in `mkpath'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/pathname.rb:1035:in `mkpath'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/installer.rb:15:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli.rb:222:in `install'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
from /usr/bin/bundle:13
╭─love@Love ~/rails/nbt1 ‹system› ‹master*› 
╰─➤  bash                                                                                                                                  1 ↵
love@Love:~/rails/nbt1$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.14
love@Love:~/rails/nbt1$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]
love@Love:~/rails/nbt1$
```

I have placed this line at the end of `~/.zshrc`.

```
 source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

I think yes, the rails wrapper script was moved to the bin directory, there might be compatibility issue.

Couple of things to get it work, bundle zsh and rvm,

1) Add to .zshrc at first line to correct find bin direcrory:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

2) Add next line after previous one:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

3) And at the end change PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Now it correct define `$PATH with all rvm gemsets`

It's work fine for me.

Thanks.

Helpful link http://railscasts.com/episodes/308-oh-my-zsh

Answer (score 1):

I had my `PATH` configured correctly, but I was still getting the error. Adding the following to my `.zshrc` file fixed the problem:

```
unalias rails
unalias rake
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code add to ~/.zshrc in last

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
```